# What should a javascript: URL do that returns neither a string nor undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

Given this HTML:

```html
<a href="javascript:123">Click here!</a>
```

clicking on the link in Firefox replaces the contents of the page with "123". In Chrome, it does nothing.

With the URL `javascript:void 123`, neither browser does anything. With the URL `javascript:'123'`, both browsers replace the page with "123". The discrepancy seems to be for anything that is neither a string nor undefined. My reading of [step 14 of section 5.6.1 of the HTML5 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#navigating-across-documents) supports Firefox’s behavior. What is the right behavior?

(Yes, I know it is bad practice to use the `javascript` scheme. I’m just curious because I saw a website that broke in Firefox because of this.)

Comment: "whose response body is the return value *converted to a string value*" -- I agree, Firefox is right.

Comment: You already found the answer in the spec (that's what the right behaviour should be). Firefox is doing it right, Chrome isn't. File a bug and wait what the developers reply. I don't think this question is right on this site.